# Teamcity SSH Upload Build step can not find artifacts of dependency build

Tags: teamcity

I have two build jobs.
`Job Build` and `Job Deployment`.

`Job Deployment` depends on the artifacts of `Job Build`

[image]

When `Job Build` ran the artifacts are available. Now I want to use the `SSH Upload` Build Step for `Job Deployment`. It asks for the sources to be deployed.

I give the following path

[image]

When I execute the build chain the `SSH Upload` Build Step failed

[image]

Can anybody tell me how to point to the artifact path?

Comment: create a buid step and lists all files in working_dir.

Comment: could you provide more information? What kind of build step should I define? A `command line build step` which will execute `ls %working_dir%` ?

Comment: yes. also `ls coopr-hq-artifacts` dir

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check your TC agent or remote host if this *.jar exists there first.
2. If yes - check the artifacts path and follow documentation:
   https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD3/Build+Artifact

Sometimes when you have a pool with more than 2 TC agents - another TC agent can run Job Deployment step - verify that you build from the same chain and on the same agent (go to agent directory and check **work** folder).